# Listview scrolling and selecting Textfield afterwards is freezing my app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the package

```
  country_code_picker: ^1.4.0
```

https://pub.dev/packages/country_code_picker#-installing-tab-

with flutter 1.17.3

Which is pretty much one of the only country code picker packages. But I have one serious problem an I don't have a clue what it could be.

When I run this code

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:country_code_picker/country_code_picker.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  App();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: TestWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: _buildCountryPicker(context));
  }

    Widget _buildCountryPicker(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Center(
        child: CountryCodePicker(
          initialSelection: 'NL',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I open the dialog to select a country. I scroll in the list and then select the TextField my keyboard opens and when I try to type something my entire app freezes. I can't even hot reload. I don't get a single error.

I am running this on my Huawei P30, but I also experience this on other android devices. I don't know if this is a flutter bug or a country code picker bug.

I think it is probably in this widget somewhere. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would help me alot!

```
class SelectionDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<CountryCode> elements;
  final bool showCountryOnly;
  final InputDecoration searchDecoration;
  final TextStyle searchStyle;
  final TextStyle textStyle;
  final WidgetBuilder emptySearchBuilder;
  final bool showFlag;
  final double flagWidth;
  final Size size;
  final bool hideSearch;

  /// elements passed as favorite
  final List<CountryCode> favoriteElements;

  SelectionDialog(
    this.elements,
    this.favoriteElements, {
    Key key,
    this.showCountryOnly,
    this.emptySearchBuilder,
    InputDecoration searchDecoration = const InputDecoration(),
    this.searchStyle,
    this.textStyle,
    this.showFlag,
    this.flagWidth = 32,
    this.size,
    this.hideSearch = false,
  })  : assert(searchDecoration != null, 'searchDecoration must not be null!'),
        this.searchDecoration =
            searchDecoration.copyWith(prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SelectionDialogState();
}

class _SelectionDialogState extends State<SelectionDialog> {
  /// this is useful for filtering purpose
  List<CountryCode> filteredElements;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SimpleDialog(
        titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        title: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              iconSize: 20,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.close,
              ),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            ),
            if (!widget.hideSearch)
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                child: TextField(
                  style: widget.searchStyle,
                  decoration: widget.searchDecoration,
                  onChanged: _filterElements,
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
        children: [
          Container(
            width: widget.size?.width ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height:
                widget.size?.height ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                widget.favoriteElements.isEmpty
                    ? const DecoratedBox(decoration: BoxDecoration())
                    : Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          ...widget.favoriteElements.map(
                            (f) => SimpleDialogOption(
                              child: _buildOption(f),
                              onPressed: () {
                                _selectItem(f);
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Divider(),
                        ],
                      ),
                if (filteredElements.isEmpty)
                  _buildEmptySearchWidget(context)
                else
                  ...filteredElements.map(
                    (e) => SimpleDialogOption(
                      key: Key(e.toLongString()),
                      child: _buildOption(e),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _selectItem(e);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );

  Widget _buildOption(CountryCode e) {
    return Container(
      width: 400,
      child: Flex(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          if (widget.showFlag)
            Flexible(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                child: Image.asset(
                  e.flagUri,
                  package: 'country_code_picker',
                  width: widget.flagWidth,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Text(
              widget.showCountryOnly
                  ? e.toCountryStringOnly()
                  : e.toLongString(),
              overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
              style: widget.textStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEmptySearchWidget(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.emptySearchBuilder != null) {
      return widget.emptySearchBuilder(context);
    }

    return Center(
      child: Text('No country found'),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    filteredElements = widget.elements;
    super.initState();
  }

  void _filterElements(String s) {
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    setState(() {
      filteredElements = widget.elements
          .where((e) =>
              e.code.contains(s) ||
              e.dialCode.contains(s) ||
              e.name.toUpperCase().contains(s))
          .toList();
    });
  }

  void _selectItem(CountryCode e) {
    Navigator.pop(context, e);
  }
}
```

Also filed an issue on the flutter github https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59886

Edit:

I have a video of it right here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=669KitFG9ek&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to remove the keys, so there probably was a duplicate key

```
 ...filteredElements.map(
    (e) => SimpleDialogOption(
      //key: Key(e.toLongString()),
      child: _buildOption(e),
      onPressed: () {
        _selectItem(e);
      },
    ),
  ),
```